# Route [proforms2.destroy2] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, web-frameworks

I wan't to make second destroy method in my controller, to delete part of bigger deletable element. I've got error in view on this line:

```
 `<td><form action="{{ route('proforms2.destroy2',$query2->id) }}" method="POST"></td>`
```

Route [proforms2.destroy2] not defined.

This is route:

```
`Route::resource('proforms2', 'ProformController@destroy2');`
```

This is ProformController.php method:

```
public function destroy2(Proform $proform, $query2)
{
$query2->delete();

return redirect()->route('proforms.edit')
->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
}
```

Comment: Your method is wrong, you are using a resource route, not a single route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to use a method call when you are using laravel **Resource**. you can do something like below:

```
Route::get('delete/proforms/{preform}','ProformController@destroy2')->name('proforms2.destroy2');
```

and in the **controller method** as below

```
    public function destroy2(Proform $proform)
{
$proform->delete();

return redirect()->route('proforms.edit')
->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
}
```

i may missed something but you can do something like that.

Comment: I have working method for delete $proform.  I want to delete $query2

Comment: Ok. You helped me to show edit page with this delete button, but when i press it i got:
The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Comment: you have to add another method for it and it will have another route as i mentioned in the code. pass an id to the route and fetch the record from database in destroy method and delete that record.

Comment: actually you have used post method in the route which is not necessary if you are deleting something. you should use get method in the form attribute.

Comment: I ve got <form action="{{ route('proforms2.destroy2',$query2->id) }}" method="GET">
in view 
and 
Route::get('delete/proforms/{query2}','ProformController@destroy2')->name('proforms2.destroy2');

and in Controller
public function destroy2(Proform $proform, $query2)
{
$query2->delete();

return redirect()->route('proforms.edit')
->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
}
But have the same error:
The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Comment: maybe the error is not because of that because we are not using any delete method in the web.php file

Comment: I don't have any delete metod in my routes. I' ve got this error only after pressing this delete button for this code whitch was pasted here

Comment: use the code which i sent you after the laravel resource

Comment: on route:list I've got 
GET|HEAD  | delete/proforms/{query2} | proforms2.destroy2   | App\Http\Controllers\ProformController@destroy2